# Web page structure not staying aligned on zooming

Tags: html, css, forms, button, flexbox

I am having problem displaying my content in proper alignment. I made a timer web app using html and css, but the display structure gets messed up when i zoom in or out in the web page. The outer box and inner button do not zoom in or out together also the buttons go into the next line when zoomed in. I have attached screenshots of how they look.

[Web page on 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sRNo.jpg)
[Zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfHIJ.jpg)

I used flex  boxes to align the components
Here is the code I wrote:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Poppins", "PT sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 13px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
  width: 55vh;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  margin: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: none;
}


/*.button::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}*/
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <center><img src="timer.png" width="40%" height="20%" alt="" id="timer">
        <br>
        <span id="countdown"> 60 </span> <span id="plural">s</span>
        <br>
        <div class="block">
          <button id="start" name="start" class="fill" onclick="startTimer()">START</button><br>
          <button id="add" name="+5" class="fill" onclick="add()">+5</button><br>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
          <button id="pause" name="pause" class="fill" onclick="pauseTimer()">PAUSE</button> <br>
          <button id="remove" name="remove" class="fill" onclick="remove()">-5</button> <br>
        </div>
        <div class="block2"><button id="end" name="" class="fill" onclick="endTimer()">END</button></div>

      </center>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="text"></div> -->
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

I just got started so any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: what's the desired outcome on zooming? Everything gets larger or it all stays the same?

Comment: `<center>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used.

Comment: @MikeB that the buttons and box get increased on decrease in proportion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing a little at what you're going for, but if I understand your correctly, your height and width values on `.container` were causing you problems. I removed them, and also replaced `<center>` with a `<div>` as Paulie commented, it is obsolete:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Poppins", "PT sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 13px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  margin: 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <div><img src="timer.png" width="40%" height="20%" alt="" id="timer">
        <br>
        <span id="countdown"> 60 </span> <span id="plural">s</span>
        <br>
        <div class="block">
          <button id="start" name="start" class="fill" onclick="startTimer()">START</button><br>
          <button id="add" name="+5" class="fill" onclick="add()">+5</button><br>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
          <button id="pause" name="pause" class="fill" onclick="pauseTimer()">PAUSE</button> <br>
          <button id="remove" name="remove" class="fill" onclick="remove()">-5</button> <br>
        </div>
        <div class="block2"><button id="end" name="" class="fill" onclick="endTimer()">END</button></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="text"></div> -->
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: if i remover the container dimensions the box becomes wider than what i want. How will i fix that?

Comment: Try adding a width, but not a height, as that was causing the issue.